# Dual OpAmp LM358

Tags: operational-amplifier

I currently developing a sensorbox for an apartment building. Two of the sensors are MQ-2 and a MQ-7. I found a schematic which uses a LM358 dual opamp.
In the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm358b.pdf) it states that there are two outputs.

Can I use one LM358 to power both MQ-Sensors?

Every symbol I found (KiCAD editor) only has 5 pins and the reference designs also only show 5 connections. Can I use both outputs on different sensors OR do I need two seperate Opamps?

Comment: LM358 is an 8 pin chip so 6 pins + 2 pwr.   You can use one dual IC as the MQ -x impedances are low so  crosstalk and interference is negl.

Comment: Then why have all the symbols in schematics only 5 connections (2Pwr and the 3 pins for signals)?

Comment: 3 pins for side a and 3 pins for side b

Comment: Ok. I think I found the 'error'. Most symbols have an A and B side and can be pointed to the same footprint. Thanks for clearing up my confusion

Comment: Why are you using an op amp to *power* your sensors?

Comment: 'Power' was the wrong word

Comment: You can make a symbol that shows both op-amps, however your schematics will not be easy to read. In the case of dual op-amps, I've used 3 part symbols- A, B and C where A & B are the amplifiers (with no power connections, just 3 pins each) and C is just the power connections.